# Formatting a set of data from Tkinter labels to insert into listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, format, label

I've got a bit of a weird issue. I have been attempting to format the data entering a `Listbox`. However, I am achieving an unusual and unintended result. Here is the snippet where the problem lies. Please assume the Tkinter window operates as normal:

```
self.alternate_cp = Label(self, text='Juanitash Rosiololopolo') 
self.list = Listbox(self) 

name = self.alternate_cp.cget('text')
date = date.today().strftime('%m:%d:%Y')
punch = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

table = [name, date, punch, 'Designated Alternate']
table_format = "{:<8}  {:>8}  {:<8}  {:8}"

for items in table:
    self.list.insert(END, table_format.format(*items, sp=' '*2))
```

And so, I get this:

[image: Result]

I tried adding square brackets around each item, which led to a tuple error.
I am attempting to have all items display on the same row when inserted into the listbox.

Thank you contributors.

Comment: Actually you are inserting only one element in each for loop, not 4.

Comment: You are inserting `name` in the 1st iteration, `date` in 2nd iteration, `punch` in 3rd iteration and `'Designated Alternative'` in the final iteration.  Do you want `self.list.insert(END, table_format.format(*table)` instead of the whole for loop block?